# Generate a component relationship diagram from Datadog traces?

Tags: automation, diagram, distributed-system, datadog

I'm hoping to generate at least a component relationship diagram from the distributed trace data available from Datadog. The live system map is great, but I want to extract this into a common diagram format so I can manipulate it myself.

It seems https://www.cloudcraft.co/ was acquired by Datadog, but they're focussed on cloud architecture.

Is there an existing tool that integrates with Datadog API and outputs a file in a common diagram format?

I've only inquired via Datadog support thus far. I expected them to know for sure, but they just pointed me to the interactive Service Catalog Map.

Comment: If I were trying to accomplish this I would focus on the Service Map API and try to convert the JSON results to Mermaid charts.